# adding button on top of the outgoing call screen in android

Tags: android

![Adding buttons on top of the default call screen of android][1]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJ8Pc.jpg

As shown in the below image, there are two buttons one is Live video button and the other is Picture share button, how to add those button on top of the default android call screen while making call.

Thanks,
Android F

Answer (score 1):

I believe the way to do this is to draw views on top of the dialer activity. This is similar, in implementation, to the Facebook home chatHead feature. Have a look at this article, which shows how to draw any view: http://www.piwai.info/chatheads-basics/

In your case, your view would be a LinearLayout containing two buttons.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, i will look at that and let you know if i get any success on that, please let me know if there are any other ways to do it...